# .htaccess redirect with multiple hypens in url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

we have move our website and decided to remove all the old news, if is there a way to redirect urls which contain '-'

here is an example of some fo the URLs we have redirect.

RedirectMatch 301 /climate-change-threatens-expose-cold-war-secrets/?$ /news

RedirectMatch 301 /countdown-to-armed-forces-day-begins-in-liverpool/?$ /news

RedirectMatch 301 /chilcot-report-the-key-findings/?$ /news

RedirectMatch 301 /cold-war-nuclear-base-uncovered-ice-melts/?$ /news

RedirectMatch 301 /corbyn-refuses-guarantee-support-nato-allies/?$ /news

RedirectMatch 301 /comment-if-were-in-a-cold-war-how-do-we-get-out/?$ /news

Is it possible to redirect anything with along these lines "word1-word2-word3-OrEvenMoreWords"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there are at least 2 words separated by `-` per news post then the following should be sufficient:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^[^\-]+(?:\-[^\-]+)+$ /news   # matches "my-post" or "my-long-post" but not "mypost" or "my--post"
```

`^` matches the start of the URL.
`[^\-]` matches all except for `-`.
`+` keeps matching the previous rule and ensures at least one is matched.
`(?:` begins a non-capturing group.
     `\-` matches the `-` character.
     `[^\-]` matches all except for `-`.
     `+` keeps matching the previous rule and ensures at least one is matched.
`)` ends the non-capturing group.
`+` keeps repeating the non-capturing group ensuring it is matched at least once - the group begins with `-` and matches at least one character up to the next `-` so in this way we allow `a-b-c-d...`
`$` matches the end of the URL, ensuring nothing remains unparsed.

Comment: thank you I am new to this so could you point me in the right direct so I can understand what that all means. Many Thanks

Comment: The regex itself or the entire `.htaccess` line? I assumed you were familiar with them since you give your own examples in both. For the regex part you could check out https://regex101.com/ to test the regex with your own input and get a brief explanation of what each part does and how it matches the input. There are many more sources for more detailed information on regex though, you'll have to  Google around if you want more on that.

Comment: Many Thanks for this I will look there now.